# Proxy test not working in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, proxy, jasmine

Code

```
var cartModule = (function() {
  var cart = [];
  var cart_proxy = new Proxy(cart, {
    set: function(target, property, value) {
      ... 
      target[property] = value
      return true
    }
  }

  return {
    toggleItem: function() {
      if (value) {
        cart_proxy.push(new Item(item_name)); 
      }
    }
    getItems: function() {
      return cart.map( object => object.name ); 
    }
  }
})
```

Spec

```
describe("when toggleitem is called", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    cartModule.toggleItem("ladder", true)
  })
  it ('adds item', function() {
    expect(cartModule.getItems()).toEqual(["ladder"]);
  })
})
```

Spec fails if the code says `cart_proxy.push`, but if code says `cart.push` spec passes. As well in console, I can confirm that `cart_proxy.push` is working appropriately. Looks like what's failing is something about the use of the Proxy

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that, you cannot make `cart_proxy` properly, and that's the main reason of your test failure. Also, your test may suffers from few issues.

You have syntax error. The correct one is below:

```
var cartModule = (function() {
  var cart = [];
  var cart_proxy = new Proxy(cart, {
    set: function(target, property, value) {

      target[property] = value
      return true
    }
  })

  return {
    toggleItem: function() {
      if (value) {
        cart_proxy.push(new Item(item_name)); 
      }
    },
    getItems: function() {
      return cart.map( object => object.name ); 
    }
  }
})
```

it means that, you forgot to close the parenthesis in the line `new Proxy(`, and secondly, you lost a `,` in the return object. Your test works, with `cart.push`, because your `cart` is an array and you can inject one more element into it, but because of the stated problem `cart_proxy` cannot be constructed.

Also, i have some concerns about your `beforeEach`:

```
 beforeEach(function() {
    cartModule.toggleItem("ladder", true)
  })
```

I think the `toggleItem` is a function in the `cartModule` which does not receive any parameter, but here it has received 2 arguments.

In conclusion, I suggest you to clean your code.

Comment: sorry! I did a bad job of copy/paste, the code works fine and doesn't have the syntax errors in actuality. as i stated, in the console, I can confirm everything works fine. Any other thoughts?

Comment: why do u pass 2 parameters to `toggleItem`, meanwhile it does not get any?

Comment: oh  no sorry bad copy paste job again, again want to emphasize the code IS working in console. I think the problem is that the proxy doesn't pass actions to the actual `cart` in test mode, or just that I don't know how to test proxy objects

Comment: can u edit your question?  i cannot see, any place which u call function `cart_proxy.push`. Your test is calling `getItems()`

Comment: `cartModule.toggleItem("ladder", true)`, when run, calls `cart_proxy.push`. The test is basically saying if `cartModule.toggleItem()` is called, does that successfully push things into the cart VIA the `cart_proxy`. It's a bit of a 2-step, but I'm not sure it can be tested separately since the `cart_proxy` is just a proxy item